# Can the custom vector in OWASP zap be set by calling API？

Tags: owasp

I want to use OWASP zap to scan the API. The data format of the API post request is JSON, but setting the input vector of zap will not fuzz the JSON data in the post request. After I set it in the user-defined vector, I will fuzz the parameters in the post request. However, I can't find the corresponding information from the API file. What's the best way

Comment: This was also asked (and is being answered) on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/cCM6P8hjfEA/m/g5LXBlwzDgAJ

Answer (score 0):

ZAP *will* attack JSON correctly, but only if it can identify that JSON data is being used, It does this by checking that the Content-Type header starts with "application/json". Based on the details supplied on the ZAP User Group the target app is not doing this. If the app cannot be changed to set the correct content type then the solution will be to write a custom input vector script which detects JSON data in another way.